# 'dds esp' on Windbg

Tags: debugging, windbg, stack-pointer

I am not sure if I am understanding the raw output of `dds esp` or its 64-bit counterpart `dqs rsp` properly. When I see a list of entries in the stack, I tend to assume that wherever I see return addresses, those are calls made by code that **have not returned yet**. IOW, stringing them together should form a nice call stack. (let's not bother with `k*` group of Windbg commands for now.) Is that not the case always?

Because there are some third party extensions, that operate on the esp/rsp output and strings together the entries into something that appear to look like a call stack but I can't seem to match that order with what I see in the source (well, whatever source I have.) There are even entries of functions that have returned long ago.

What am I missing?

*UPDATE:*

OK -- the third party extension I use does say:

`Dumps (dps) from the stack limit the base only showing items that include the ! followed by +0x`

So, the question then becomes what *is* that entry? I thought it was the return address of some function that is fixing to make a call into another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dds` means **d**ump **d**words (32 bit) and interpret the result as a **s**ymbol. Similar for `dqs` (quad word, 64 bit) and `dps` (pointer-size, matching the architecture).

If you read that again, you'll find the term *symbol* as the abbreviation, not *stack*. Any number which happens to be in memory will be interpreted as a symbol, if possible. That may be a method call on the stack. And it may also be a local variable which accidentally has a value matching a symbol.

Those local variables are probably not counter variables like `i` and `j` but maybe `float` or `double` data type, which are hard to predict how they look  like in memory. Also, `struct`s might have a layout that results in an in-memory representation that looks like a symbol.

The extension you mention seems to do a simple `dps` and filter lines which do not have a symbol associated.

Still, `dps` is helpful in cases of stack corruption, although you need to have a good understanding of what your application does, i.e. which symbols can be on the call stack and which symbols cannot be there.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I suppose that means listing out esp/rsp is not a reliable indicator of whether a thread ended up executing a particular function or not? (i.e going by some symbol names that _look like_ function addresses.)